# WIX Toolset MSI. How to read folder name from registry?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, registry

This code gives me the value of the PowerShellVersion key.

```
 <Property Id="POWERSHELLVERSION">
      <RegistrySearch Id="POWERSHELLVERSION"
                      Type="raw"
                      Root="HKLM"
                      Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\PowerShellEngine"
                      Name="PowerShellVersion"/>
 </Property>
```

How can I get the name of the folder?
For example, I need to find the name of the PowerShellEngine folder in folder 3 and assign it to Property "POWERSHELLVERSION".

```
 <Property Id="POWERSHELLVERSION">
      <RegistrySearch Id="POWERSHELLVERSION"
                      Type="raw"
                      Root="HKLM"
                      Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3"
                      Name="PowerShellEngine"/>
 </Property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would assign the value C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 to POWERSHELLLOCATION.

```
 <Property Id="POWERSHELLLOCATION">
      <RegistrySearch Id="POWERSHELLVERSION"
                      Type="raw"
                      Root="HKLM"
                      Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\PowerShellEngine"
                      Name="ApplicationBase"/>
 </Property>
```

Comment: Thanks! 

How to add to POWERSHELLLOCATION only the value "v1.0"?
Now POWERSHELLLOCATION="C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0".
I want it to be POWERSHELLLOCATION="v1.0".

Comment: you need to write a custom action to read the property, parse the property and set the property.  It has to be scheduled after AppSearch as this is the built in standard action that reads the registry into the property.